# Send output of print to a new file in python?

Tags: python, printing, output

In this section of a program I'm making now I converted a plain sequence of letters into fasta format. I need to take this fasta format and put in a file form so I can send it to a program which will come later in the code. In line 3 I created "fasta.txt". I need to put the output of line 8, fastaform, in that file. In the last line I tried to do this but it didn't work and I have no idea how. I feel like this should be pretty simple to do but I'm new at this.

```
infname = sys.argv[2]
handle = open(infname, "r")
file = open("fasta.txt", "w")
for line in handle:
        linearr = line.split()
        seqid = linearr[0]
        seq = linearr[1]
        fastaform = (">%s\n%s\n" % (seqid,seq))
        print fastaform >> "fasta.txt"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
file.write(fastaform)
file.close()
```

Comment: Thank You! I should have thought to do that.